# Save newest mail attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using VBA code that downloads any attachment in an Outlook mail to a specific folder.

I am calling the code in a "run a script" Outlook Rule where I have defined which mail this has to work for.

The code works from a new to old fashion providing me the oldest attachment and not newest attachment. This is for the attachments with same name in every mail.

What shall I add to the below code so that it moves in an old to new sort, downloading new attachments to override old attachments with the same name.

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem) 
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment 
Dim saveFolder As String 
saveFolder = "E:\Projects\Takeda\Data\Zipped Incremental data\incremental\"      
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments          
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName          
    Set objAtt = Nothing      
Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: A rule will process items as they are received. The attachment in the most recently received item will be the last one saved. I believe the problem, as described in the question, cannot occur. How are you processing items in reverse chronological order? Are you as well running the code on a folder of already received items?

Comment: If the item has multiple attachments with same name, then look for datelastmodified file

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the `itm's` attachments collection, it has a `count` property that holds the count of attachments. You can get the count, then in your for loop step backwards through the count. Inside your for loop, just refer to the attachments object using an index to refer to the individual attachment items in the attachments object:

```
Dim attachmentCount as integer    
Dim saveFolder As String 
saveFolder = "E:\Projects\Takeda\Data\Zipped Incremental data\incremental\" 
attachmentCounter = itm.Attachments.count     
For i = attachmentCounter to 1 Step -1          
    itm.Attachments(i).SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & itm.Attachments(i).DisplayName        

Next
```